# Скрыть кусочек пончика не заполняя недостающее

Tags: javascript, диаграммы, chart.js

Вопрос касается Doughnut от Chart.js

Есть ли какие то варианты скрыть кусочек пончика не заполняя недостающую часть другим ?

Или же, отключить эффекты при наведении на какой либо кусочек ?

В дефолте так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поменять цвет с синего на белый ?

Comment: Решение было бы быстрее дано, если бы вы предоставили код того что по дефолту